# Modification of Admin Generator's Doctrine Form layout

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need to modify Admin Generator's Doctrine Form which is included by:

```
$this->embedRelation('MyRelation');
```

The default layout looks like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

The goal - every Item of Select should be displayed as text in separate row, plus Price and Quantity:

[image: Screenshot 2]

schema.yml

```
Game:
    actAs:
      Timestampable: ~
    columns:
      id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
      game_name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
    indexes:
      it:
  fields: game_name
  type: unique

  Campaign:
    actAs:
      Timestampable: ~
    columns:
      id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
      name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
      is_active: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0 }
      start: { type: datetime, notnull: true }
      end: { type: datetime, notnull: true }
    relations:
      CampaignMatrix: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: id, foreign: campaign_id, foreignAlias: CampaignMatrixCampaign }

  CampaignGames:
    actAs:
      Timestampable: ~
    columns:
      id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
      campaign_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
      game_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
    indexes:
      tc:
  fields: [campaign_id, game_id]
  type: unique
    relations:
      Campaign: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: campaign_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: CampaignCampaignGames }
      Game: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: game_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: GameCampaignGames }

  CampaignMatrix:
    actAs:
      Timestampable: ~
    columns:
      id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
      item_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
      campaign_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
      price_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
      quantity: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
    relations:
      Item: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: item_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: ItemCampaignMatrix }
      Campaign: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: campaign_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: CampaignCampaignMatrix }
      Price: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: price_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: PriceItems }

  Price:
    columns:
      id: { type: integer(4), unsigned: true }
      currency_code: { type: string(3), notnull: true }
      price: { type: float, notnull: true }
    indexes:
      tc:
  fields: [id, currency_code]
  type: unique

  Item:
    actAs:
      Timestampable: ~
      I18n:
  fields: [name, description, image]
    columns:
      id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true, unsigned: true }
      game_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
      product_id: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
      price_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
      quantity: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unsigned: true }
      name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
      description: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      image: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    indexes:
      it:
  fields: item_type
    relations:
      Game: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: game_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: GameItems }
      Price: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: price_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: PriceItems }
```

This is how I do it:

```
$list = MainItemTable::getInstance()->findByGameId($gameId);

$CampaignMatrix = new CampaignMatrix();

foreach($list as $index => $item) {

    $itemAssocForm = new CampaignMatrixForm($CampaignMatrix);
    $itemAssocForm->item_id = $item->getId(); // Need it in the form as hidden field
    $this->embedForm($item->getProductId(), $itemAssocForm);
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to get the value:

```
$this->widgetSchema['item_id'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('value' => $this->item_id)); // It doesn't get the Id
```

But I have an error:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php on line 237

1. If I unset price_id in CampaignMatrixForm, no error produced. How to avoid execution of select of  the same data for every item row in the loop?
2. Item id is missing, but I need it as hidden field. How to pass CampaignMatrix ID of current row to CampaignMatrixForm?

Comment: can you post the relevant tables from your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate on association to emebed the association form to the main form. It mays be simple if you post a part of your schema.yml.

Try to re-use this snippet :

```
$list = MyRelatedObjectTable::getInstance()->findAll();

foreach($list as $item)
{
  $itemAssoc = AssociationTable::getInstance()->findByObjectId($this->object->id, $item->id);

  if(!$itemAssoc)
  {
    $itemAssoc = new Association();
    $itemAssoc->value_id = $itemAssoc->id;
    $itemAssoc->user_id = $this->object->id;
  }

  $itemAssocForm = new AssociationForm($itemAssoc);
  $this->embedForm('itemAssoc'.$item->code, $itemAssocForm);
}
```

Comment: So how do you access preference_id and user_id in Form?

Comment: Your model is maybe too complex... try to refactor CampaignMatrix in CampaignGames. To achieve your goal, you have to deeply invest yourself in custom form creation and processing. Make a custom form class, load custom widgets and widgetSchema. For processing, make your own dobind and save method for update your doctrine objetc. EmbedForm suffers of bad design, and maybe simply won't fit your goals.

Comment: I couldn't update data with my form, but only insert... Inserted Items couldn't be pre-selected in the embedded form. Seams like I need to make it totally custom. I think AJAX will help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a partial for that. Be aware that you need to `unset` the select box for the Item in the Form class or you'll lose your association. I can elaborate on that if you need more help.

Comment: Why will association be lost if I have not unset Item select?

Comment: if the submit action does not receive any information in that field (widget is not rendered), is like submitting an empty field. That clears the value. **But**, the best option would be converting the field to a `sfWidgetFormInputHidden` - that keeps the association and prevents the value from being lost.

Answer (score 0):

you can get code from cache and move to your backend/modules/nameAPP and next edit template

Comment: this doctrine form. I think there should better way.